# PHP MYSQLi real_escape_string

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

this is my query run code:

```
$sqlm = getPageById();
if ($resultm = $mysqli->prepare($sqlm)) 
{
    $mypageid = 216;
    $resultm -> bind_param("i",$mypageid); 
    $resultm->execute();    
    $resultm->store_result();
    $rowsm = $resultm->num_rows;
}
if($rowsm > 0)
{
    $rowm = fetch($resultm);
    $pagetitle = $mysqli->real_escape_string($rowm[0]["page_title"]);
    $pageContent = $rowm[0]["page_content"];
    $pageurlname = $mysqli->real_escape_string($rowm[0]["page_name_url"]);

}
```

And this is my query:

```
function getPageById()
{
    $sqlStr = "select * from tbl_pages where page_id = ?";
    return $sqlStr;
}
```

And this is what I am send in post:

```
$mysqli->real_escape_string ($_POST["page_content"]);
```

And this is my `echo`:

```
$pageContent = $rowm[0]["page_content"];
<?=$pageContent?>
```

i get a problem in the echo
i get the results from the database like this:

in stead of: stackoverflow ..
i get: stack/r/n//over/r/n/flow
any help please?

Comment: And the issue is in...?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question in your question.

Comment: @michael: What problem are you having? What error message do you get?

Answer (score 1):

`mysqli_real_escape_string` is used for sanitizing string that you're going to interpolate into a SQL query (if you use this old-fashioned way instead of using prepared statements). It's not used for processing the *results* of a query.

If you're going to be inserting the results into a web page, the function you want is `htmlentities`. E.g.

```
$pagecontent = htmlentities($rowm[0]["pagecontent"]);
```

Using prepared statements when you query the database prevents SQL injections. Using `htmlentities` when you put the results on a web page prevents Cross-site Scripting attacks.

Comment: do you mean that when i inserts into the database i dont need real_escape_string? ...
this what i sent in $_POST: `$mysqli->real_escape_string ($_POST["page_content"]);` ,,, what code i should use in post and what in echo the results into my page ?

Comment: Do you mean that i dont need to use
`$mysqli->real_escape_string`? and just:
`$string = $_POST["fieldname"];` ?
and in processing the rsults of a query just to echo:
`$name = $row["name"];`
`echo $name;`?

Comment: I don't see any inserts in your original question, so I can't tell if you need to use mysqli_real_escape_string. It depens on how you write the insert -- if you use `$mysqli->prepare` you don't need to use it.

Comment: ah ok man :D thank you :D ... i am yes using `$mysqli->prepare` in all of my queries, insert,edit,update , thank you mr.@Barmar

Comment: Yes, it seems to be a SELECT, not an INSERT.

Comment: yes, all my queries is in prepared statements...the select the update the insert the delete...all of them in prepared statement... in the select i remove the bind_param line...and its work currectly

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if the data is the problem, not your php code. Are you sure those newlines aren't in the database?

Comment: yes, they are in the database:S ... because of this i put my $_POST code :S ... they stock in the database!